# MVC return Action search for current Actionresult's view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
  public ActionResult xyz(int? page)
        {
            return Index(page);
        }
```

What I want to do is xyz return same thing as index. I just want to define two url which is actual same. I check that it's trying to find xyz.cshtml

it's not look good. I thing it will just return index function and it's done. It's amazed me. Do someone can show me here if I return the index function directly then how it can search xyz.cshtml.

Someone please tell me the way so index.cshtml is used and the way I return Index show the page as I want.

Paritosh's answer make return the page that I want. but it's create problem that nothing is passed now through Viewdata and Viewbag.

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            int pagenum = page ?? 1, limit = Globals.xyz_PAGE_SIZE;

            int startrow = (pagenum - 1) * limit;

            ViewBag.xyzCount = xyz.xyzget();
            ViewBag.Pagesize = Globals.xyz_PAGE_SIZE;
            ViewBag.xyz= blahblah.xyz(startrow, Globals.xyz_PAGE_SIZE + 1);
            return View();
}
```

my meaning to create the another action is just create two url. what about if i do it with routing. Is routing is better option or their is no good way to deal with this trouble.

Comment: return `View()` statement missing...is this typo error?

Comment: @Paritosh Actually The code is huge so I copy few part.I fix it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass view name here

```
public ActionResult xyz(int? page)
{
    return View("Index",page);
}
```

If you don't pass View name, then it'll search view which is having same name as Action method - which is `xyz.cshtml` here. That's why you were facing issue

Comment: It is return the page but it's not working. All the passed ViewData and ViewBag is now NULL (that has been added from Index().

Comment: You have to share the complete code for it. What you are passing in `ViewData` & `ViewBag`, what is the ViewModel, and yes, then it'll be another question :)

Answer (score 2):

In fact you have two choices :

```
//immediately show the "Index" View
return View("<Path_To_Index_View>", page);
```

Or

```
//Redirect to the "Index" Action
return RedirectToAction("Index", page);
```

Choose the one you need.